# bundle exec rake routes is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, twitter-bootstrap, rake-task

When I run `bundle exec rake routes`, it prints this messages:

```
Faraday: you may want to install system_timer for reliable timeouts
rake aborted!
undefined method `debug_rjs=' for ActionView::Base:Class

Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This started to happen when I installed the gem `twitter-bootstrap-rails`

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: can you run `bundle exec rake routes --trace` and update the question with its output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstall the bootstrap and everything went back to normal XD

Answer (score 3):

Comment this line in `config/environments/development.rb`  (if working on development)

```
# config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
```

It's because the newer rails version remove debug_rjs, you updated you rails but didn't update 
your `development.rb`

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d8f23ca627df85b33fe8db87db5483c10b62bfe6

add this to your `Gemfile`

```
 gem "system_timer", "~> 1.2.4"
```

and run

```
 bundle install
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. but I am on a production mode. and I don't see the config.action_view.debug_rjs on config/environments/production.rb

I also installed the gem "system_timer" without any version specification to match the compatibility of my other gems by default.

Comment: Maybe you can try to find `debug_rjs` in all of the app files. and then delete them.

Comment: This throws some heavy error log then fails… : Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. /Users/bbnnt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Answer (score 0):

Try installing system_timer gem and then retry what you are doing.

To install system_timer gem

```
gem install system_timer
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already tried install system_timer gem but still can't view my route using `bundle exec rake routes` :C